# Connection to app pool dropping IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, application-pool

I have a WCF service which is hosted in one of our environments and causing problems only in this environment. The service is dropping if the request takes longer than 5 minutes to execute. (I timed it)

I enabled Trace logging for the WCF service and found nothing of interest in the generated `.svclog` files. There is nothing in the `EventViewer` also. I do notice that the `HTTPERR` file has some logs in it.

`httperr`

```
2018-06-12 00:17:31 **.*.***.*** 40028 **.*.***.** 20601 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2018-06-12 00:45:47 **.*.***.** 30947 **.*.***.** 20601 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2018-06-12 00:47:57 **.*.***.** 53295 **.*.***.** 20601 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2018-06-12 00:47:57 **.*.***.** 47352 **.*.***.** 20601 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2018-06-12 00:59:44 **.*.***.** 25663 **.*.***.** 20601 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2018-06-12 01:04:50 **.*.***.** 35450 **.*.***.** 20601 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2018-06-12 01:07:40 **.*.***.** 48289 **.*.***.** 20601 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2018-06-12 01:19:36 **.*.***.*** 62695 *.*.***.** 20601 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2018-06-12 01:20:56 **.*.***.*** 57339 *.*.***.** 20601 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2018-06-12 01:26:46 **.*.***.*** 42058 *.*.***.** 20601 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2018-06-12 02:14:52 **.*.***.*** 59815 *.*.***.** 20601 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2018-06-12 02:38:12 **.*.***.*** 2487 *.*.***.* 20601 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2018-06-12 06:14:37 **.*.***.*** 47072 *.*.***.** 80 - - - 400 - Verb -
2018-06-12 13:03:52 **.*.***.** 23883 *.*.*.** 20601 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2018-06-12 13:08:47 **.*.***.** 32002 *.*.*.** 20601 HTTP/1.1 POST /SomeUrl/SomeService.svc - 2 Connection_Dropped Foo-SomeService-AppPool
2018-06-12 13:32:22 **.*.***.** 45018 *.*.*.** 20601 HTTP/1.1 POST /SomeUrl/SomeService.svc - 2 Connection_Dropped Foo-SomeService-AppPool
```

I checked the `Timer_ConnectionIdle` [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364693(v=vs.85).aspx) and increased the `Connection Timeout` setting within the site in IIS, but the same happened. (Increased it from `120` to `240`). What's strange about the `httperr` file which I don't understand is the `DateTime` field. The `Timer_ConnectionIdle` starts at `00:17:31`, but it should have dropped them earlier than `13:08:47`.

The `Connection_Dropped` from the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364693(v=vs.85).aspx) means:

> IIS failed to return the logging data within the specified time limit (1 minute) due to a client disconnect (or reset) before the response was logged.

So the connection was dropped before IIS even got a chance to log why it dropped. What else can be causing the `Connection_Dropped` from the app pool?

Comment: As a note on the oddities in the `DateTime` field: do the times check out if you assume that they are created in `Utc`, and not your local time zone?

Comment: @AndreasBjørnHassingNielsen You are right. 13 UTC is 9AM est. I was testing around then, and the `Connection_Dropped` was in fact around 5 minutes after `9:03 AM est`. But this still doesn't really help in terms of why the connection was dropped.

Comment: You will need other data to assist this analysis, like WCF tracing and network packet capture. Merely HTTP error log won't give you a clear image of the situation.

Comment: @LexLi I have WCF tracing enabled on the `Information` level, but nothing is getting logged as with a `Error`/`Warning`/`Critical` level. I do notice that the `.svclog` is not complete, meaning it was created with errors in the xml. Could this mean too many resources where required for the application pool, so the logging just stopped logging abruptly?

Comment: @Jimenemex. did you find anything on this one - I'm facing an exactly similar issue.

Comment: Sadly I cannot remember what the solution was, but I would recommend enabling all the logging you can in WCF and IIS. I believe I figured it out by enabling failed request tracing in IIS for requests that lasted longer then 4 minutes. @AdityaPednekar